# Modern SharePoint - Date field not getting saved

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, date-time

Facing an issue with the Date fields in Modern SharePoint. When I type in the date or select a date and then change the year (by manually editing in the input box), it does not get saved.

It used to work in classic SharePoint and still does on the same site in classic mode but not in modern.

[image]

Changed the year in the text input:

[image]

It does not get saved. Default date is set to today. Even if you do not set default date, it will save as a blank if I enter/edit the date using the input text box.

[image]

Has anyone faced this issue? Is it a known Modern SharePoint issue/limitation?

I searched on the UserVoice if anyone has raised this but couldn't find anything.

Is there any workaround for this (please do not suggest editing the form using PowerApps)?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce this issue on our SharePoint site & observed the same behavior for **Date only** columns.

However, it is working as expected for **Date and Time** columns.

I will suggest to create a Support ticket with Microsoft for this issue.

---

**Update**:

Manual input in date field is working for me on **Standard release** tenant. Facing this issue on **Targeted release** tenants.

Comment: Yes it works when it is a Date & Time but not when it is a Date only

Answer (score 0):

**---------------------------Update-------------------------------**

The result is the same as you when creating a new item, we recommend you get support from Microsoft.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/business-video/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide

**---------------------------------------------------------------------**

I could not reproduce your issue in SharePoint online with Date only column:

[image]

Please check if the issue occurs on other lists/libraries/sites.

[image]

Comment: I have tried on 2 separate tenants on multiple lists. It does not work for me.

Comment: @Julie_MSFT, you are trying this on **Edit/Details form** & for me, this issue is happening for **New item** form.